# How to join 2 tables on fields which have different formats?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

```
Table A:
id  - number
a_d - text
```

where `A.a_d` has the text format: "`yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`" (examples: `2001-08-22 00:00:00`, or `2002-03-23 00:00:00`)

```
Table B:
id  - number
a_d - text
```

where `B.a_d` has the text format: "`dd-month-yyyy`" (example: `01-jul-2002` or `09-feb-2005`)

I want to run join query on the text fields of those table.

```
select a.a_d
from A a
join B b
on a.a_d =?=  b.a_d
```

- I can't change or update the tables, just get data from them

How can I compare this 2 fields, if there have different format ?

Comment: **Never** store date or date/time (=timestamp) values in `text` columns. Use a proper `date` `timestamp` or `timestamptz` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_DATE` to convert the text dates into bona fide dates before comparing:

```
SELECT a.a_d
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
    ON a.a_d::date = TO_DATE(b.a_d, 'DD-mon-YYYY');
```

Note that the `a_d` field in table `A` happens to be a text timestamp which can already be directly cast to date, so we only need `TO_DATE` for the `B` table.

Ideally you should store your dates and timestamps in proper columns rather than text.  Then, the join would be possible without costly conversions.